# Shortcode para Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Estou usando a IP API para geolocalização em um plugin do wordpress, o plugin está pronto e funciona normalmente! Eu quero acrescentar o seguinte:

Em um dos campos do plugin, o usuário pode inserir um texto e no final desse texto, só que esse campo não aceita shortcode, é um tipo de campo de texto comum, sem editor nem nada, vou anexar a imagem. O shortcode já está pronto, so preciso que o campo aceite o shortcode, por enquanto ele só traz o shortcode como texto.

Código de Saída

```
$loop_link_rows .= '<div class="coluna_relacionados_fake"><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="/?action=count&id=' . $row->meta_id . '"><img src="'.content_url().'/uploads'.$row->meta_attachment.'" alt="'.esc_attr( stripcslashes($row->meta_title)).'"></a><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="/?action=count&id=' . $row->meta_id . '">'.$row->meta_content.'</a></div>';
```

[image: Shortcode no campo de texto]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para o shortcode funcionar você precisa chamar um filtro, ou ativá-lo diretamente.

O jeito mais simples é chamar o filtro [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/), que aplica todos os filtros definidos para o conteúdo padrão, inclusive ativando os shortcodes. Serve melhor se você tem texto junto com o shortcode.

```
// Supondo que sua meta-key seja "chave"
$meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'chave', true );
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $meta_value );
```

A outra forma é chamar [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) diretamente.

```
// Supondo que sua meta-key seja "chave"
$meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'chave', true );
echo do_shortcode( $meta_value );
```

Aplicando no código:

```
$loop_link_rows .= '<div class="coluna_relacionados_fake">
    <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="/?action=count&id=' . $row->meta_id . '">
        <img src="'.content_url().'/uploads'.$row->meta_attachment.'" alt="'.esc_attr( stripcslashes($row->meta_title)).'">
    </a>
    <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="/?action=count&id=' . $row->meta_id . '">'
        .apply_filters( 'the_content', $row->meta_content ).
    '</a>
</div>';
```

Comment: Tentei fazer aqui, mas não funcionou, só apliquei os filtros na minha função.. Pelo menos eu entendi que era isso! Vou postar uma Foto do que fiz.

Comment: Você deve aplicar os filtros onde você precisa que o shortcode seja expandido. Normalmente isso é no template onde ele vai ser usado, na hora de imprimir na tela mesmo. Lembrando que shortcodes não se expandem dentro de `input` ou `textarea`

Comment: Eu preciso que o campo $row->meta_content aceite shortcodes, então eu fiz isso. http://imgur.com/a/0Qu7f

Mas, é um campo de textarea, se esse for o problema, qual campo me indica?

Comment: Então, `apply_filters()` retorna o conteúdo com o shortcode expandido mas você não está usando esse retorno. Vcê precisa colocar isso onde tá a segunda menção a `$row->meta_content` ali. Copia esse trecho ali na pergunta e eu atualizo com o exemplo.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta

Comment: Atualizado com o código.

Comment: Acho que estamos quase lá hein, só apareceu um erro no front agora
http://imgur.com/a/bxlq4

Comment: Esse erro não é relacionado, é o xDebug que tá reclamando do numero de nesting levels. A solução é desativar o xDebug ou aumentar o limite, veja aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656089/solution-for-fatal-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-abor

Comment: Show, vou procurar como resolver esse erro!

Comment: Com do_shortcode($row->meta_content) não da esse erro nenhum! Vlw pela ajuda!